# Deque Pointer Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a struct in which i have used std::deque

```
class VariantWrapper;
typedef _STL_NAMESPACE_::deque<VariantWrapper> VariantQueue;

struct AttributeValueWrapper
{
AttributeValueWrapper() : bAttributeIsArray(false)
{
    pVariantQueue = new VariantQueue;
    if(!pVariantQueue)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
}
AttributeValueWrapper(const AttributeValueWrapper& a)
{
    pVariantQueue = a.TakeOwner();
    bAttributeIsArray = a.bAttributeIsArray;
}
AttributeValueWrapper& operator=(AttributeValueWrapper& r)
{
    throw std::bad_exception("equal operator not supported in AttributeValueWrapper");
}
VariantQueue* TakeOwner() const
{
    VariantQueue *p = pVariantQueue;
    pVariantQueue = NULL;
    return p;
}
~AttributeValueWrapper()
{
    if (pVariantQueue)
    {
        delete pVariantQueue;
    }

}

bool bAttributeIsArray;
mutable VariantQueue *pVariantQueue;};
```

Main Method:

```
int main()
{
 AttributeValueWrapper attrib;
}
```

I am running this code under Dr Memory (This is just a piece of code , project is quite big) and Dr Memory showing  a memory leak at 
`pVariantQueue = new VariantQueue` inside the default constructor
as:

> Error #46: LEAK 8 direct bytes + 324 indirect bytes
>   replace_operator_new
>       d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c(2899):
>   std::_Allocate<>
>       ??:0
>   std::allocator<>::allocate
>       ??:0
>   std::_Wrap_alloc<>::allocate
>       ??:0
>   std::_Deque_alloc<>::_Alloc_proxy
>       ??:0
>   std::_Deque_alloc<>::_Deque_alloc<>
>       ??:0
>   std::deque<>::deque<>
>       ??:0
>   AttributeValueWrapper::AttributeValueWrapper

Please share you thoughts on this issue.

I have also tried using `std::unique_ptr`, but still getting the same memory leak at same line no(same point):

```
struct AttributeValueWrapper
{
AttributeValueWrapper() : bAttributeIsArray(false)
{
    pVariantQueue = std::make_unique<VariantQueue>(new VariantQueue);
    if(!pVariantQueue)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
}
AttributeValueWrapper(const AttributeValueWrapper& a)
{
    pVariantQueue = a.TakeOwner();
    bAttributeIsArray = a.bAttributeIsArray;
}
AttributeValueWrapper& operator=(AttributeValueWrapper& r)
{
    throw std::bad_exception("equal operator not supported in AttributeValueWrapper");
}
std::unique_ptr<VariantQueue> TakeOwner() const
{
    std::unique_ptr<VariantQueue> p = std::move(pVariantQueue);
    pVariantQueue = NULL;
    return p;
}

~AttributeValueWrapper()
{

}

bool bAttributeIsArray;
mutable std::unique_ptr<VariantQueue> pVariantQueue;
```

};

Now getting memory leak at

`pVariantQueue = std::make_unique<VariantQueue>(new VariantQueue);`

Vinay

Comment: Any reason why you don't just make the dequeue a member variable?  You can still move its contents around efficiently using std::swap()

Comment: Please share more code, minimal complete example would be great.

Comment: `pVariantQueue = std::make_unique<VariantQueue>(new VariantQueue);` are you sure you don't want `pVariantQueue = std::make_unique<VariantQueue>();` ? Probably you create new `VariantQueue` and then call copy constructor in the `make_unique`? Thus memory allocated by new is leaked.

Comment: I tried it making member variable, but then i am getting "memory lot allocated to deque" error and application got crashed.

Comment: @Satus - i have also tried pVariantQueue = std::make_unique<VariantQueue>();                                                          But still getting the memory leak.

Comment: @VinayKumar Well, without complete code we can only guess. I don't see any leaks except this: `make_unique<VariantQueue>(new VariantQueue);`.

Comment: I concur with @Satus `make_unique<VariantQueue>(new VariantQueue)` That literally makes no sense. It should be `std::make_unique<VariantQueue>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory leak can most likely be found in the destructor. What happens to the objects in the queue when the queue goes away?